# Get inserted rows on a Linked server database table of a vendor (can't create trigger)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, linked-server

I need to simulate an AFFER insert trigger on a table in a linked server Database that is read only from a Vendor.

I can't change the table but I can read.

Beside creating a stored proc on our server and schedule it to run every  X minutes to get net changes, can someone point me to a design more dynamic?

Thank you.

Comment: If the database is `READ ONLY`, how can the data be changing? The statements conflict.

Comment: If you only have read access then your only option is to poll it. There is no magical way to detect changes.

Comment: Hello Larnu,

the data base is linked to PDA that update that DB but we the customer only have read access to that Database . 
we can create a Linked server on the SQL express and the database but we can<t create a AFTER TRIGGER on The table receiving the PDA information ot Link It back to our Central system.

So my intention is to create a stored Procedure that query that Linked Table and insert missing information based on a query listing missing rows. Schedule that with SQL agent to run every X minutes.... 
Not very elegant ..... but it woudl do the job